# Issue sorting multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Im having this issue with this filter of a site that im developing, basically i need to put all the categories together:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ag11L.png)
[image]

I need to put all the categories together, that means that all the "sistema operativo" and "disco duro" options should be together, not at the end of the list (pictured). I tried to achieve this with an array_push() and the in_array function, but at the end it just displays again these last options.

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
$filterTitle = array();
foreach($resultFiltro as $filtros){ // titulo de categoria
        if (!empty($_SESSION['filterId'])){ 
            $resultDatos = filtroCategoriasDatos($filtros['id_padre']);                     
            $resultFiltroDos = filtroDatosEspecificosFiltros($filtros['id'], $in[0]);
        }else{
            $resultDatos = filtroCategoriasDatos($filtros['id_caracteristica']);                        
            $resultFiltroDos = filtroDatosEspecificos($filtros['id_caracteristica'], $in[0]);
        }   

            <div class="grupo_filtro">
            <?php 
            //if(!in_array($resultDatos[0]['titulo'], $filterTitle)){ ?>
                <div class="titulo_filtro">
                    <?php echo $resultDatos[0]['titulo'];?>
                </div> 
            <?php array_push($filterTitle, $resultDatos[0]['titulo']);?>
            <?php //} ?>
                <div class="con_filtros_filtro">
                    <?php foreach($resultFiltroDos as $select){ ?>
              <div class="filtro atributo <?php echo $class;?>" titulopadre="<?php echo $resultDatos[0]['titulo'];?>" id="<?php echo $select['id'];?>">
                            <?php echo $select['titulo'];?>
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php 
            } ?>
```

i dont know if this can be fixed sorting the recordset in some way or if there is other trick that can help me with this.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Show a before and after of the array. What it is, and what you need it to be.

Comment: Post the original array_structure along with the expected output

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be your solution

```
<?php 
$filterTitle = array();
foreach($resultFiltro as $filtros){ // titulo de categoria

?> <div class="grupo_filtro"> <?php

        if (!empty($_SESSION['filterId'])){ 
            $resultDatos = filtroCategoriasDatos($filtros['id_padre']);                     
            $resultFiltroDos = filtroDatosEspecificosFiltros($filtros['id'], $in[0]);
?>
                <div class="titulo_filtro">
                    <?php echo $resultDatos[0]['titulo'];?>
                </div> 
            <?php array_push($filterTitle, $resultDatos[0]['titulo']);
        }else{
            $resultDatos = filtroCategoriasDatos($filtros['id_caracteristica']);                        
            $resultFiltroDos = filtroDatosEspecificos($filtros['id_caracteristica'], $in[0]);


     ?>
                <div class="con_filtros_filtro">
                    <?php foreach($resultFiltroDos as $select){ ?>
              <div class="filtro atributo <?php echo $class;?>" titulopadre="<?php echo $resultDatos[0]['titulo'];?>" id="<?php echo $select['id'];?>">
                            <?php echo $select['titulo'];?>
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php 
            }} ?>
```

Comment: no. it just displays in the same way sistema operativo and disco duro at the end.

Comment: Try again I just changed something, can you put what the functions filtroCategoriasDatos and filtroDatosEspecificos are doing?

Comment: Hi. The problem was in the function. I added an order by and it was fixed. Thank guys for your help

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the function. I added an order by and it was fixed. Thank guys for your help.

here i attach the function

```
function filtroDatosEspecificosFiltros($datoPadre, $in=""){
global $db;
if($in != ""){
    $filtroCategoriaDos = "SELECT p.titulo, pc.id_atributo, pc.id_caracteristica, p.id, pc.id_producto FROM principal p INNER JOIN producto_caracteristica pc WHERE p.id=".$datoPadre." AND p.id=pc.id_atributo AND visible=1 AND pc.id_producto IN (".$in.") group by pc.id_atributo";
}else{
    $filtroCategoriaDos = "SELECT p.titulo, pc.id_atributo, pc.id_caracteristica, p.id, pc.id_producto FROM principal p INNER JOIN producto_caracteristica pc WHERE p.id=".$datoPadre." AND p.id=pc.id_atributo AND visible=1 group by pc.id_atributo";
}
$resultDatos = $db->getAll($filtroCategoriaDos);

usort($resultDatos, function ($elem1, $elem2) {
    return strcmp($elem1['titulo'], $elem2['titulo']);
});

return $resultDatos;
```

}

thanks for all the help.